# Calculating confidence interval as quantile

Tags: python, confidence-interval

I need to find the 95% confidence interval as 2.5 and 97.5 quantiles

```
boot_mean_diff = []
for i in range(3000):
    boot_before = before_proportion
    boot_after = after_proportion
    boot_mean_diff.append(boot_after.mean()-boot_before.mean())

# Calculating a 95% confidence interval from boot_mean_diff 
boot_mean_diff=pd.Series(boot_mean_diff)
#boot_mean_diff1=boot.boot_mean_diff(frac=1,replace=True)
confidence_interval = pd.Series(boot_mean_diff).quantile([0.025,0.975])
confidence_interval
```

However, I am getting the error below ----

> AssertionError: confidence_interval should be calculated as the [0.025, 0.975] quantiles of boot_mean_diff.

Comment: What are `before_proportion` and `after_proportion`?

Comment: Its the proportion of deaths before a particular period and after a period. The datatype is Series

Comment: I tried your code, with some fake 1-D data I made up for `before_proportion` and `after_proportion`, and it works fine. Could you edit your code to provide a minimum working example, including those two Series?

Comment: I get the output too.  in a matrix form                                                                                                    0.025   -0.083957
0.975   -0.083957
dtype: float64

Comment: If you're getting an output, where is the error raised?

Comment: I am doing it on datacamp. It raises the above mentioned error.

Comment: Alright, I'm not sure how DataCamp does its checks, but it might have to with the fact that your lower and upper limits are equal (-0.083957), which is fishy. That happens if your before and after proportions are always the same within the loop. Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you

Comment: @Esha Did you found the solution

Answer (score 0):

I was too facing the same error. Try the below code

```
# A bootstrap analysis of the reduction of deaths due to handwashing
boot_mean_diff = []
for i in range(3000):
    boot_before = before_proportion.sample(frac=1, replace=True)
    boot_after = after_proportion.sample(frac=1, replace=True)
    boot_mean_diff.append(np.mean(boot_after) - np.mean(boot_before))

# Calculating a 95% confidence interval from boot_mean_diff 
confidence_interval = pd.Series(boot_mean_diff).quantile([0.025, 0.975])
print(confidence_interval)
```

I have used import numpy as np, thus using np.mean()
you can directly try with boot_after.mean()